# Method is not being executed on button_Click event

Tags: c#, mysql

In my Visual Studio project, I create a button for each record on a table (MySQL)through a foreach statement, each button is created through this method:

```
    void createRewardButton(int y, int rewardsAmount, string rewardName, int value)
    {
        int x = 200;

        //Create Button object
        Button rewardButton = new Button();

        ///Set button properties
        rewardButton.Name = "button"+rewardName;
        rewardButton.Height = 60;
        rewardButton.Width = 400;
        rewardButton.Location = new Point(x,y);
        rewardButton.Text = "You won "+ rewardsAmount + " awards for  " + rewardName + ". Value: " + value + " tokens";
        rewardButton.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        rewardButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

        //Add button to Awards Panel
        panel_Rewards.Controls.Add(rewardButton);

        ///Button event handlers
        rewardButton.MouseHover += new EventHandler(rewardButton_MouseEnter);
        rewardButton.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(rewardButton_MouseLeave);

        ///Event handler for the click method
        rewardButton.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => rewardButton_Click(sender, e, value));

        //Button controls 
        void rewardButton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rewardButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Gray); ;


        }
        void rewardButton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rewardButton.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

        }
        // On click control method
        void rewardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, int rValue)
        {
            increaseTokens(rValue);
        }
    }
```

I want each button to execute the increaseTokens() method on every click,  the method requires an int parameter. I found that I could use lambda syntax for the event handler to use "value" as a parameter on the rewardButton_click event.

Here is the code of the increaseTokens method:

```
void increaseTokens(int value)
    {
        ////Connection String//////////
        string connStr = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=scores;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=password;";
        //Connection object
        MySqlConnection dbcon = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            dbcon.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Message: " + err.Message);
        }

        if (dbcon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            String query = "UPDATE agents SET agentTokens = @value WHERE agentEid =  @EID";
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbcon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EID", EID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("value", value);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
```

The buttons are created but the database is not being updated when the buttons are clicked. Since I'm not getting any error or alert I don't know if the rewardButton_click event is accepting the int parameter and passing it to the increaseTokens() method.

Any information on how to fix that would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you debugged that, setting a break point in your handler to verify what is called? I'm not sure you are capturing the `value` correctly, I would attach the value to the buttons `.Tag` and read it from there. I think if you "un-inline" the methods your problem will work itself out.

Comment: Since you want to increment a value in the database, have you considered changing your Update statement to `UPDATE agents SET agentTokens = agentTokens + 1 WHERE agentEid =  @EID`

Comment: Debug your application. You can easily set a breakpoint inside createRewardButton, and inside increaseTokens to check if the int value is being passed.
That way you'll also know if increaseTokens() is even called at all when you click one of the reward buttons.

Comment: @Flydog57 you are right, the right query for my purposes would be `UPDATE agents SET agentTokens = agentTokens + @value WHERE agentEid =  @EID`

Comment: If you just went into the Code portion and manually added in the click event, it may still need to be added to the other portion(s) of the project. I would recommend double clicking the button in the `form.cs [Design]` tab and making sure it doesn't add another event.

Comment: Maybe you should create the buttons, after  that search for Button Controls . and perform a click. 

i dont know why do u need it. but maybe will solve your problem.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten  just updated the query and now I can see the value modified on the database. Thanks!